# Экспорт "шрифтовой" графики из Photoshop

Tags: html, css, photoshop

Как экспортировать графику из Photoshop, которая сделана шрифтом?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну так посмотрите что за шрифт и используйте его в своем проекте, либо преобразовать в смарт объект и сохранять в картинкой

Comment: @Elena преобразовал в смарт объект, попытался экспортировать, показывает пустую картинку

Comment: Тогда еще и растрировать, затем выделить область где находится иконка, скопировать, сохранить

Comment: Подключать шрифт, чтобы использовать один единственный символ из него? Не проще бы перевести в svg картинку? Или, если знаете, что в масштабировании картинка не будет участвовать (анимация увеличения при ховере, например), то ещё лучше будет просто сохранить как картинку. Для этого создайте новый документ, скопируйте элемент и скорректируйте размеры изображения, чтобы все пиксели влезли. Но если прямолинейно отвечать на вопрос, то нужно подрубать шрифт в страницу через тег `<link>`, вставлять этот символ, а затем корректировать положение и размеры через css. Но это глупо.